# преобразование в String без экспоненциального формата

Tags: c#

Метод `toString()` возвращает длинные числа в экспоненциальном формате (например, `(0,000001).toString()` вернет `1Е-06`). А как получить строку с числом в обычном числовом формате? Я знаю про спецификаторы формата, но не могу вывести максимально возможное количество знаков после запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, плохо я знал про спецификаторы формата. Спецификатор `F` по умолчанию оставляет только два знака после запятой, если же нужно больше, то просто добавляется их количество, например: `F10`, `F6`.

```
double doubleNumber;
doubleNumber = 18934.1879;

Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Результат: 18934.19

Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Результат: 18934

doubleNumber = -1898300.1987;
Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
// Результат: -1898300.2
```